# Соотношение понятий, выраженных существительными во множественном и единственном числе

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, семантика, управление, словосочетания

I. «Спектры света и звука»

Какой смысл?

1. Спектры света и спектры звука.
2. Два спектра — спектр света и спектр звука.

II. «Функции этих контуров мне неизвестны»

1. У каждого контура своя функция.
2. У каждого контура несколько фукнций.

III. «Эти контуры выполняют свои функции хорошо».

1. Каждый контур выполняет одну функцию.
2. Каждый контур выполняет несколько функций.

IV. «Все контуры выполняют свою функцию хорошо».

1. Каждый контур выполняет одну функцию, одинаковую с функциями остальных.
2. Каждый контур выполняет одну функцию, отличную от функций остальных.

Есть ли для автора какое‑то правило построения конструкций указанных типов, чтобы они были однозначными, а для читателя — правило определения точного смысла подобных конструкций или всё решается индивидуально исходя из логики ситуации c конкретными понятиями, а автору рекомендуется составлять текст так, чтобы читатель всё верно понял?

Огромная просьба при ответе на вопрос не углубляться в понятия света, звука, контуров. Половину из вышеприведённых предложений я придумал, просто чтобы были примеры. Нас интересует общий метод решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В каждом из этих случаев однозначность или неопределенность зависят не от грамматики, а от **контекста**.

*В первом* примере читатель с некоторой подготовкой (средней школы достаточно) поймёт смысл *однозначно*: спектр в обоих случаях - одна и та же математическая абстракция (зависимость интенсивности излучения от частоты), а не несколько, а множественность (спектры) относится к двум существительным (у каждой названной сущности свой спектр). Вне дополнительного контекста даже специалист не станет предполагать частные разновидности спектра света (спектр поглощения его в такой-то и в другой среде и т. п.).

*Во втором* случае допускаются множественные функции, и у говорящего на этот предмет нет ясности: *по его же словам*, ему это неизвестно.

*В третьем* случае вне дополнительного контекста можно предположить, что хотя бы один из контуров имеет более одной функции. В противном случае (у каждого контура своя функция) данная грамматическая конструкция требует пояснительного контекста (почему у одного контура одна функция, а у другого такого же - другая; какие именно эти функции).

*В четвертом* примере грамматическая конструкции оправдана лишь при наличии предшествующего пояснения, например, что все контуры выполняют одну *общую* функцию, например, защиты от чего-то, и работают *совместно*. Вне контекста предложение повисает в воздухе: приходится строить догадки, какую же особенную функцию выполняют все эти контуры. При отсутствии контекста лучше сказать: "каждый из этих контуров..." (у каждого своя функция; неважно, различаются ли они у разных контуров).

Comment: Однозначные варианты для примера III: "каждый контур выполняет свою(и) функцию(и) хорошо" или "каждый контур выполняет эту функцию хорошо", а слово "эту" объяснить в контексте. Вообще, местоимения  и местоименные слова (каждый, эта и т.п.) полезны и необходимы для обеспечения однозначности.